# creating a registration form

Tags: registration

Alright let me explain my situation first:

I am part of an organization that "hosts" events. For example, we have an annual camp, skating, hocket/soccer tournaments, dinners, and the like.

Now they want me to design their website. My habit is usually to put it on paper first so I am trying to do that. But the problem is here:

They need a registration form. But for every event/activity the questions asked are different. For example for the annual camp, theres a question "What allergies do you have?". For the hockey tournament theres a question "Whats your favourite jersey color" and "Name the 5 other people in your team". *

*note: there are generic questions like name/age/location/phone/email.

Also please keep in mind that these people dont know a thing about web development and how to use it. I know this because I've already made them a website with an admin panel but they still find it too confusing (and also the part where I have to create teh "custom" registration form).

I am now thinking of how to incorporate this. Ideally I'd like all this information to go to a database.

My options 
1) Using online registration form to capture generic information. Pass a PDF link but open the PDF in the BROWSER with the ability to write on it. Upon submitting, the newly saved PDF can go to an email.

2) .. well thats all I have right now lol.

Anyone have suggestions/solutions?

thanks a lot!

tech used: c#/vb.net ASP.NET!

Comment: Sorry but what does the PDF file have to do with all this?

Comment: The organization will create a PDF with all the questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sort of app has been done 1000x times over.  Use one of them.  Evite if you must.

Or one of these [Evite alternatives](http://www.evitealternatives.com/).

Or, use a [Google App Form](https://drive.googleblog.com/2008/02/stop-sharing-spreadsheets-start.html).  Works wonders for small events.

Answer (score 1):

A database that stores which questions go with which types of forms.  A web interface to display the appropriate form for a given event.  A second web interface for their admin to easily view/add/remove questions to each type of form.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to do this, but some questions require a textbox and some require a combobox, some will require radiocheckbox. I understand I dont have this functionality when using PDF but with an online form I'd like to prevent spam.

Comment: No reason you cant do that with dynamically generated forms.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to chart designs like this out first you might like [Product Planner](http://productplanner.com/). They have tons of existing registration patterns there  too.

Answer (score -1):

Store a list of questions and input types: textbox, textarea, etc. Then get the list of questions with the form's id when building the form, inserting HTML based on the type of question. Then store the data back into the database when the user submits the form by form id and question id.